# OpenShift OC new-app parameter substitutions not working

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I can't seem to perform any parameter substitution.

```
oc new-app -f template.yaml -p MEMORY_REQUEST=2G
oc new-app -f template.yaml -p MEMORY_REQUEST="2G"
oc new-app -f template.yaml --param=MEMORY_REQUEST=2G
oc new-app -f template.yaml --param=MEMORY_REQUEST="2G"
oc new-app -f template.yaml --param-file=myapp.properties (contains MEMORY_REQUEST=2G)
```

All result in

```
error: unexpected parameter name "MEMORY_REQUEST".
```

The yaml template looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: template
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: myapp
    name: myapp
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: myapp
      deploymentconfig: myapp
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: myapp
          deploymentconfig: myapp
      spec:
        containers:
          - image: myapp:1.1.1
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: myapp
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8888
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: ${MEMORY_REQUEST}
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't define a parameters section in your template, so it will reject any parameters you try and give it.

Best to see the documentation on templates and parameters at:

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-parameters

Comment: Right.  Thanks Graham.  It wasn't clear to me from the documentation that I had to also define the parameters section.  I thought it would just pick things up automatically from the parameters file or parameters arguments.  Ps. I might come back with more questions! :) (currently, in the middle of the learning stage.)